# $a<b(b+2)$ then $f(a)< 2f(b).$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, elementary-number-theory

I am looking for a positive continuous function $f$ such that for all positive $a,b>0$

> $$a < b(b+2)\Longrightarrow f(a)<2f(b)$$ and $$a=b(b+2)\Longrightarrow f(a)=2f(b).$$

Does such a function exist?

I tried to constructing one using exponential functions, as they are positive, but I failed.

Comment: well, I tried to construct one using exponentials, as they are positive, but I failed.

Comment: To rewrite: $$a+1<(b+1)^2 \Longrightarrow f(a)<2f(b)$$ seems a bit easier to work with than the original condition.

Comment: And what about f(x)=1?

Comment: @Clayton 1<2(1) = 2 is always true.

Comment: Any positive constant function satisfies your condition regardless of $a,b$.

Comment: The range or the domain is always positive?

Comment: @F.Carette you should submit as the answer.

Comment: we also want to have $a=b(b+2)$ then $f(a)=2f(b).$ Sorry for that, I had this in mind, but did not write it down. Otherwise, the question becomes a bit stupid.

Comment: I do not think so. It was just a missing condition, it happens, I am not asking something entirely different now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: My guess: $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}c\log x$$ or something similar

Comment: @InterstellarProbe this function is not positive.

Comment: Ah, good point. But, I think that is a function that satisfies that $f(x^2) = 2f(x)$, which is close to the your condition that $a+1=(b+1)^2 \Longrightarrow f(a)=2f(b)$. So, any function that does satisfy is going to be close to a logarithmic function. And if that is positive on $(1,\infty)$, then it will not be positive on $(0,1]$.

Comment: The required function is $f(x)=log(x+1)$ and its positive multiples based on hint by @InterstellarProbe.

Comment: I downvoted because OP has not specified the domain of definition of the required function. If we put $g(x) = f(x-1)$, then $g((x+1)^2) = f(x^2+2x) = 2f(x) = 2g(x+1)$. That is, we have $g(y^2) = 2g(y)$ (on whatever domain). So, any multiple of any logarithmic function will do (for $g$). Hence, $f(x) = c\log_a(x+1)$ satisfies the second condition.

Comment: @Sascha Why have you deleted your follow-up question? I have been thinking about to find an answer for you for quite some time. I don't think this is a good behaviour from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb{R}_{>1}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be defined by $g(x):=f(x-1)$ for all $x>1$.  Thus, if $a,b>0$ satisfies $a<b(b+2)$, or equivalently, $(a+1)<(b+1)^2$, then
$$g(a+1)=f(a) < 2\,f(b)=2\,g(b+1)\,.$$
If $a=b(b+2)$, which is the same as $(a+1)=(b+1)^2$, then
$$g(a+1)=f(a)=2\,f(b)=2\,g(b+1)\,.$$
Thus, if $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $$h(t):=\dfrac{\ln\Big(g\big(\exp(2^t)\big)\Big)}{\ln(2)}\text{ for all }t\in\mathbb{R}\,,$$
then
$$h(t+1)=h(t)+1\text{ for all }t\in\mathbb{R}\,.\tag{*}$$
That is,
$$f(x)=2^{h\left(\frac{\ln\big(\ln(x+1)\big)}{\ln(2)}\right)}\text{ for all }x>0\tag{#}\,.$$

In other words, you can start with any continuous function $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies (*).  Then, any such a function $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ must take the form (#).  In particular, if $h(t)=t+\ln(c)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and for a fixed $c>0$, then
$$f(x)=c\,\ln(x+1)\text{ for all }x>0\,.$$
There are, however, infinitely many other solutions.  For example, we can take $$h(t)=t+p(t)\text{ for all }t\in\mathbb{R}\,,$$
where $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an arbitrary continuous periodic function with period $1$.  Then,
$$f(x)=2^{p\left(\frac{\ln\big(\ln(x+1)\big)}{\ln(2)}\right)}\,\ln(x+1)\text{ for all }x>0\,.$$
For example, one can take $p(t)$ to be any function in the $\mathbb{R}$-span of
$$1,\sin(2\pi t),\cos(2\pi t),\sin(4\pi t),\cos(4\pi t),\sin(6\pi t),\cos(6\pi t),\ldots\,.$$
The only thing you may have to worry about is that $h$ should be a strictly increasing function.  However, that can be easily fixed by demanding that $p(t)$ be continuously differentiable almost everywhere with $p'(t)>-1$ for almost every $t\in[0,1)$ (this extra condition will remove some viable choices of $p$, though).  That is, something like $$p(t)=\frac{\cos(2\pi t)}{2\pi}\text{ for all }t\in\mathbb{R}$$
will also work.